# How to install the wash command in SUSE?

Tags: linux, suse, zypper

I'm trying to install the `wash` command in my Singularity definition file. The singularity definition file uses SUSE12 and I can use the zypper command to install stuff. I tried:

```
zypper search -s wash
```

But could not find any related package. How can I install the wash command in SUSE?

Comment: `/usr/bin/wash` is provided by the package reaver : `# zypper in reaver` ( rpm search http://rpm.pbone.net/ )

Comment: @KnudLarsen I see, thanks. I tried it but I get `No provider of 'reaver' found.`. How to know which repository do I need to add?

Comment: Pacman (extra) it is. ......... Suse 12.3 example https://ftp.gwdg.de/pub/linux/misc/packman/suse/12.3/Extra/x86_64/ ...... How could you know : By following the link from your search at http://rpm.pbone.net/